# How to create a Join using petapoco MVC4

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, petapoco

I need to join 2 table using petapoco MVC4
my table cong shown below

```
[TableName("District")]
[PrimaryKey("nDistrictID")]
public class District
{   
    public int nDistrictID { get; set; }
    public string cDistrictName { get; set; }
    public bool bActive { get; set; }
    public int nStateID { get; set; }
}
```

And state table

```
[PetaPoco.TableName("States")]
[PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("nStateID")]
public class States
{
    public int nStateID { get; set; }
    public string cStateName { get; set; }      
}
```

I need a query in this form

```
select d.cDistrictName,s.cStateName, d.nStateID from District
       d inner join States s on d.nStateID=s.nStateID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have already a dataContext which contains 2 DbSet of each classes. Regarding that you can use: 
Regarding the result you expect, you can create a new class which matches with the result:

```
public class DistrictWithState
{
  public string cDistrictName {get;set;}
  public string cStateName {get; set;}
  public int nStateId {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your Action:

```
  var dataContext = new PetaPoco.Database("mysql"); 
  var sql="select d.cDistrictName,s.cStateName, d.nStateID from District
   d inner join States s on d.nStateID=s.nStateID";

  var districts = db.Fetch<DistrictWithState>(sql);

 return view(districts);
```

There is another solution using the `dynamic` keyword. But just start with that solution above. It should work. I hope it will help